# How to lock a MSSQL (2017 Linux) account after N unsuccessful login attempts

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017

I have to configure account lock after N unsuccessful login attempts on MSSQL 2017 Linux. That is standalone server and is not in AD. 
I couln'd find any valuable information so far unfortunately. Perhaps because Linux platform is quite fresh for MSSQL Server. Thank you for any advice here.

Comment: I believe the lockout functionality depends on the `NetValidatePasswordPolicy`API, which is Windows only.

Comment: Are you talking about locking a *SQL Server* login account? Theoretically if the instance is logging unsuccessful login events, you could periodically check the event log and count by login, as long as they all happen within the current error log cycle (which can fluctuate depending on activity and what you are logging, since it's a rolling log).

Comment: The goal here is to pass internal audit. Defense mechanism is needed and exact threshold N need to be on place to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a server / login trigger. Aaron Bertrand wrote a cool little article about combining login triggers and extended events here - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3582/prevent-and-log-certain-sql-server-login-attempts/